# Wagtail filter by related model field in PagesAPIViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, wagtail, django-filter, wagtail-apiv2

I have `EntryPage` model that have M2M relation to `Category` (`categories` field name).

I've added viewset for `Entries`:

```py
class EntriesViewSet(PagesAPIViewSet):
    base_serializer_class = EntryPageWithSiblingsSerializer
    model = EntryPage
    body_fields = PagesAPIViewSet.body_fields + EntryPageWithSiblingsSerializer.Meta.fields
    listing_default_fields = PagesAPIViewSet.listing_default_fields + EntryPageWithSiblingsSerializer.Meta.fields
    detail_only_fields = ["prev_entry", "next_entry"]
```

Now I want to be able to filter entries by Category's name. Like following: `/wt/api/nextjs/v1/blog_entries/?categories__name=name`. Is there easy way to do that using existing `FilerBackends`, or I need to write my own?